# LaunchDarkly deprecated aliasing

Tags: launchdarkly

LaunchDarkly has gotten rid of the aliasing feature. I was wondering if there is a feature similar to aliasing that can pair two different userIds into the same bucket.

I tried downgrading my version of launchdarkly but that did not work.